# How can I adapt my faucet to a dishwasher connection?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, dishwasher, kitchen-sink

I'm looking for one of those table top dishwashers. I can use the sink's tap if it has a screw end. The problem is that [mine](https://victoriaplum.com/browse/all-kitchens/category_Kitchen-taps?csi=KCHTAP53&ds_kid=92700071561870975&gclid=Cj0KCQjwmouZBhDSARIsALYcouocSFcosajvYn-M4eC0F6oNMAVRUWSTizxkHZesrJIDS4cYKcwXZccaArQ4EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) doesn’t.

Can anyone think of a way to adapt this tap to get a screw end on?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See those little flats on the tap nozzle? Those are for a wrench. Underneath is a threaded connection. Perchance it's the one you seek.

Dishwashers often come with various adapters. If not, your local hardware store probably has something that will adapt the connections.

Put some tape on the wrench to avoid scratches.

Comment: the super-fine threads on the end are used to retain the aeration screen.  Notorious for breaking off.

Comment: I've had adapters that use them. The key is to not be removing and reinstalling constantly. Leave the adapter in place once it's fitted.

Comment: There are different threadings on those sinks.  some have some especially fine threading made out of what seems like pot metal, and attaching a heavy brass fixture  and a big hose will strip or break the threads.

Answer (score 2):

Easy!  Remove the aerator and replace with a "faucet aerator to garden hose adaptor".   You don't have to get the swiveling one like in this picture but I think it will put less stress on the aerator threads.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you absolutely must get one of those things,  and from what I've heard, they are more trouble than they are worth,  go under the sink and put in a 'T' fitting with a ball valve.  Then drill a hole in the counter and run the hose down to the connection under the sink.  Now you your dishwasher has a dedicated connection.
If you are feeling especially motivated, you can even put a dishwasher elbow in your drain and sink a second hole and run the drain under the sink as well.  Then you don't have a sink full of all the grease that was on your dishes.

Comment: Although this does not actually answer the question, I prefer this approach to the one in my answer because you can use your sink while the machine is running.

Comment: if you're going to run it from under the sink there's no reason to drill a hole in the counter.

Comment: he described it as a countertop version.  I guess that you could put it in a cabinet, but if you have that much space, might as well just remove the cabinet and put in a real dishwasher.

Comment: If you're going to use a counter top dishwasher and install an under counter tap to connect it to, bring the connector to just inside the sink cabinet door and run the connector through the door instead of drilling holes in the counter top. Open the door, hook up the hoses, turn on the tap (under counter), wash dishes. When done, disconnect & close door.

Comment: @FreeMan then your kid grabs the hose and yanks the dishwasher off the counter.  Plus, when you disconnect it, you spill water all over the  floor.